# How to prevent line breaks within in description?

Tags: line-breaking, description

Basic question, but I'm just seeking out how to prevent line breaking when using `description`. I'm very new to latex, so I'm unsure of how it works. The code I have is here.

```
\begin{description}  
\item[Lane 1]NEB 1kb Ladder  
\item[Lane 2](Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid  
\item[Lane 3](Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid  
\item[Lane 4](Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid
```

I aplogize, to clarify what I mean by line breaking, I mean that I want to prevent the spacing inbetween each item in the list.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragment into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. What do you mean by "prevent line breaks"?

Comment: You might also find this helpful, more generally: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `enumitem` package.  The manual will tell you how to get the spacing right.  It's to do with the label size, I suspect.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description*} \item[Lane 1]NEB 1kb Ladder; \item[Lane 2](Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid; \item[Lane 3](Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid; \item[Lane 4] (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.  
\end{description*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline `description*` of `enumitem` (JPI answer) is ugly because the huge space after labels and the lack of hyphenation of the items have little sense in this mode:

> [image: ugly solution]

In this case, is better `paralist`:

> [image: mwe4]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{inparadesc}
\item[Lane 1.] NEB 1kb Ladder,
\item[Lane 2.] (Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid, 
\item[Lane 3.] (Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid and
\item[Lane 4.] (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.  
\end{inparadesc}
\end{document}
```

But, in this case ,as the label have a counter, it is better  return to `enumitem` and use `enumerate*,` and moreover, control what goes between items, and include " and " between the two last items automatically. I left in red all that is included automatically (of course, remove colors for a real work):

[image: mwe2]

Or if you prefer end the item punctuation manually, or not include any, then another option is define your own environment (same output that above using paralist) without using enumitem, o may be intented as with some vertical separastion:

[image: mwe3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parskip 1em
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcounter{descinline}

\def\ditem{\addtocounter{descinline}{1}\textbf{Lane \arabic{descinline}}.~}
\begin{document}

\begin{description*}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=*]
\item[Lanes 1]NEB 1kb Ladder; 
\item[Lane 2](Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid; 
\item[Lane 3](Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid; 
\item[Lane 4] (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.  
\end{description*}

\begin{enumerate*}[label={\textcolor{red}{\bfseries
Lane\,\arabic*:}}, itemjoin={\textcolor{red}{, }} ,
itemjoin*={\textcolor{red}{ ,\ and\ }}]
\item NEB 1kb Ladder
\item (Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid
\item (Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid
\item (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.  
\end{enumerate*}

\newenvironment{descinline}{\setcounter{descinline}{0}}{}   
\begin{descinline}%
\ditem NEB 1kb Ladder.  
\ditem (Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid,   
\ditem (Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid and   
\ditem (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.
\end{descinline}

\renewenvironment{descinline}{\setcounter{descinline}{0}
\list{}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{4em}}\item[]\relax}{\endlist}   
\begin{descinline}%
\ditem NEB 1kb Ladder,  
\ditem (Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid,   
\ditem (Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid and  
\ditem (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.
\end{descinline}

\end{document}
```

Or, why reinvent the weel? There are aslo `inparaenum` (the ouput is the same that `inparadesc`, but labels are now typed automatically)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[\bfseries {Lane}~1.]
\item NEB 1kb Ladder,
\item (Single Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid, 
\item (Double Digest) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid and
\item (Undigested) pET-41a/EGFP Recombinant plasmid.  
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```